# Decline in impact count

Tags: support, profile-page

Is it possible for the impact count to go down on a SE site?

I have a fairly active profile on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema?tab=profile). The *people reached* count from my various posts touched ~1.4m around a month ago. But today I happen to notice that the count has gone down to ~1.3m.

I have always observed this number going up. The uptick was prominently visible when the number was in hundreds and thousands.

Is it ever possible for this number to go down? If yes, what possibly causes this? I don't remember deleting any of my posts in a long while (last 3-4 months).

Has some recent change in SE engine caused this (corrected) count?

Comment: I’d put my money on your last sentence. The calculation was announced as very approximate from the get-go, maybe they’re trying to refine it.

Comment: @DanBron Hmm. The ~1.4m mark was touched around a month and half ago. I had the most active profile consecutively for last three months (April-June). It certainly has to be a drastic change to cause a downfall of around 100K!

Comment: Yes, large changes in the stat is possible due to cases where one of your answers on an highly viewed question is on the tipping point of being eligible for being included or excluded.

Comment: @rene Sorry I didn't catch it. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: The formula takes number of answers and their score into account for calculating your people reached statistic. There are cases where one of your answers might no longer contribute to your people reached stat because other, better answers, floated to the top. When that happens your people reached stat drops. It is not a statistic that show an contstant increment and is influenced by how well other answers on the same question do, scoring wise.